# iPhone/iPad offline web app manifest with several html pages

Tags: ios, html, ios5, mobile-safari, offline

This is my first iOS web app, so please bear with me. I coded the HTML5/CSS3 part so now I need to make this app available in an iPhone/iPad for offline viewing. I was referring to [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html) on how to compose the offline.manifest file, but I'm not clear about a couple of details:

1. The document above seems to refer to a single offline page. But obviously my web app consists of more than one page. Is it possible to make all of them available offline under one web app? If so, then how?
2. For my web app I do not link to an html page from a web browser. Each page is served by a PHP script. More over pages might have URLs like so: "http://mysite.com/home" that translates to "http://mysite.com/home/index.php" So which URL should I actually use in the offline.manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

If youre using PHP it isn't going to be an offline app. PHP code is executed server-side, so without an internet connection (offline), the app wouldn't work anyways. If its something that doesn't require php and can be rewritten in javascript, then you could make it work.

Comment: Well, php is used to output html content. Html itself can be cached and used while offline. That's what I mean. Still what about several pages?

Comment: I just thought you had the PHP script output a dynamic page.